# Multiple user login using single form

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

hello i need your help pleas guys i am new to work on vb.net 2008 and sqlserver 2005 i have a problem ...
I make table 1(For employee),(For Employee fields are [empl_No,empl_ID,empl_Password,User_type]) ,,, In which User_type(Administrator and Instructor,Student)
I want to know that When Admin login then show Form1 and when Instructor login the show Form2 and if student then form3... 
Now Plz correct my code ... *** My code ***

```
       Try
            cn.Close()
            cn.Open()
            qry = "Select User_Type from employee_tbl where User_Type= 'Admin' and empl_ID= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'and empl_Password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dr.Read()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid User Name and Password" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Please Enter Right User name And Password" & vbCrLf & " Or Sign Up For New User Account ")
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                TextBox2.Text = ""
                TextBox1.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox("Please Contact to Your System administration ")
        End Try
```

This code is working but this only for admin but i want each type of user can login which are present to databse ... please implement it and help me out ... :)

Comment: Please, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: And [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/226002/why-should-passwords-be-encrypted-if-they-are-being-stored-in-a-secure-database).

Answer (score 1):

Don't select `where User_Type= 'Admin'`. Instead, just retrieve the user type, and let your app react accordingly.

Comment: Hello Thanx its through this each type of user can login but i want that when aDmin login then show form2 and when instructor login then show form 3 *** My code Is ***  on next comment

Comment: qry = "Select User_Type from employee_tbl where empl_ID= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'and empl_Password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dr.Read()

Comment: If dr.Read = "Select User_Type= 'Admin' from employee_tbl where empl_ID= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'and empl_Password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'" Then
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            ElseIf dr.Read = "Select User_Type = 'Instructor' from employee_tbl where empl_ID= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'and empl_Password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'" Then
                Me.Hide()
                Form3.Show()

Comment: Else
                MsgBox("Invalid User Name and Password" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Please Enter Right User name And Password" & vbCrLf & " Or Sign Up For New User Account ")

Comment: Please read my all comments and give me a solution